# Is there a way to add a form field depending on a condition on Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, dynamic, field

Friends. This is the first question I ask here; so, any feedback will be welcome.

I'm new to Symfony; the version in which I'm working is 3.4
I already implemented three Type classes for my form and the structure is something like this:
There is a Registry which has a header plus zero, one or more questions. Each question is a "RegistryElement" which consist on zero, one or more answers plus an "elementScore" and an optional "elementComment."

The Type classes buildForm methods look like this:

On RegistryType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('registryHeaderId', RegistryHeaderType::class, array(
            'label' => false,
        ))
        ->add('registryElements', CollectionType::class, array(
            'label'=>false,
            'entry_type' => RegistryElementType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
                'tokens'=>$options['tokens'],
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array("attr"=>array(
            "class"=>"form-submit btn-success",
            "style"=>"margin:10px;"
        )))
        ;

}
```

On RegistryElementType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('registryElementAnswers', CollectionType::class, array(
            'label'=>false,
            'entry_type' => RegistryElementAnswerType::class,
            'entry_options' => [
                'label' => false,
            ],
            'allow_add' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
        ->add('elementScore', CheckboxType::class, array(
            "label"=>'type.registry_element_type.score',
            'required' => false,
            "translation_domain" => "FirstPieceBundle",
        ))
        ->add('elementComment', TextType::class, array(
            "label"=>'type.registry_element_type.element_comment',
            "required"=>false,
            "attr"=>array(
                "class"=>"form-name form-control",
            ),
            "translation_domain" => "FirstPieceBundle",
        ))
        ;

}
```

And, on RegistryElementAnswerType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('answer', TextType::class, array(
            "label"=>false,
            "required"=>false,
            "attr"=>array(
                "class"=>"form-name form-control",
            ),
            "translation_domain" => "FirstPieceBundle",
        ))
        ;

}
```

Now, what I would like to know is if there is a way to "add a different type of field" depending on a condition. Something like this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    if(condition){
        $builder
            ->add('answer', TextType::class, array(
                "label"=>false,
                "required"=>false,
                "attr"=>array(
                    "class"=>"form-name form-control",
                ),
                "translation_domain" => "FirstPieceBundle",
            ))
            ;
    }
    else{
        $builder
            ->add('answer', ChoiceType::class, array(
                "label"=>false,
                "required"=>false,
                "attr"=>array(
                    "class"=>"form-name form-control",
                ),
                "translation_domain" => "FirstPieceBundle",
            ))
            ;
    }

}
```

I tried to pass some values through the $options array, but I really got stuck here.
I'd really appreciate your knowledge and guidance.

Greetings.

Comment: It's surprisingly challenging to do the sort of thing you asking about especially if the condition comes from your entity.  [Form events](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/events.html) is your starting point.  Specifically the PRE_SET_DATA.  And off-topic but unless you need to maintain legacy project then you really should move to Symfony 5 or at least 4.4.  3.4 is no longer maintained.

Comment: Form events are useful, if your condition is based on the data. if it's not (or if you're willing to handle this a bit dirty), setting a new option via the forms `setDefaults` (which can be overridden in the createForm in controller) will work.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for your comments. I'll be checking out Form events to try to find a way to implement what I need. I've already tried to handle the problem in a dirty way, without success, but I just thought of a new way which I didn't try yet. Off topic, too, thanks for the advice about using a supported version of Symfony, but the enterprise in which I'm an intern has everything already built in Symfony 3.4 and moving to a newer version would be kind of a struggle. If I find a way to solve my problem, I'll share it as an answer. Have a good day.

Comment: Did you try Symfony Doc [How to Dynamically Modify Forms Using Form Events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your condition you need to use there?

If you want to pass data in the `$options` array, you will need to add the option key as a required option in the `configureOptions` method.

Let's say you want to pass `condition` in the `$options`, your `RegistryElementAnswerType` class should contain:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setRequired('condition');
    }
```

Now you are required to pass this option whenever you are referring to the `RegistryElementAnswerType`.